# Subgaussian increments of excess risk for Lipschitz functions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, random-variables, lipschitz-functions

So the problem I'm having trouble with is part (a) of exercise 8.4.9 in Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability book.

The setup is as follows. Let us define a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ and a target function $T$ as follows:

$$\mathcal{F}=\{ f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, ||f||_\text{Lip} \leq L\}$$

and a target function $T:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$.

Let $X, X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be iid. Show that the random process

$$X_f = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n [(f(X_i)-T(X_i))^2-E(f(X)-T(X))^2]$$

where $f\in \mathcal{F}$, has subgussian increments:

$$
||X_f-X_g||_{\psi_2} \leq \frac{CL}{\sqrt{n}}||f-g||_\infty
$$

$C$ is an absolute constant.

For some reason I am having a really hard time trying to show this. I have already tried the usual tricks such as rewriting the expectation in terms of another iid variable $Y_i$ so that you can write

$$X_f = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[(f(X_i)-T(X_i))^2-(f(Y_i)-T(Y_i))^2]$$

And tried manipulating this expression around, but I always got stuck trying to bound

$$||f(X_i)^2-g(X_i)^2 - (f(Y_i)^2-g(Y_i)^2)||^2_{\psi_2}$$

But I couldn't get $L$ and $||f-g||_\infty$ terms to come out simultaneously.

Comment: I am not sure if the assumptions are correct and I suspect that it should be $1$-Lipschitz functions $f:[0,1]\to [-L,L]$ instead. Now for the original assumptions, since $f-T$ is also $L$-Lipschitz, we may assume that $T=0$ and the whole thing boils down to show that $\|f^2-g^2-\mathbb{E}(f^2-g^2)\|_{\psi_2}\leq CL\|f-g\|_\infty$. Now, take a large constant $K$ and take a function $h$ such that $\|h\|_\infty\leq \epsilon$ and let $f = K+h/2$ and $g=K-h/2$. Then what we want becomes to bound $\|Kh - \mathbb{E} Kh \|_{\psi_2} = K\|h-\mathbb{E} h\|_{\psi_2}$.

Comment: Now, we can either bound $\|h - \mathbb{E}h\|_{\psi_2}$ by $2\|h\|_\infty$ or a constant multiple of $L$ if $h$ is $L$-Lipschitz. Still you can choose $K$ to be arbitrarily large and I don't think we can have an upper bound for $\|f^2-g^2 - \mathbb{E}(f^2-g^2)\|$ without a boundedness assumption on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I also struck at this problem, it seems that there exists some mistake in the problem